# How to remove the first and last 3 lines of a text with a batch script?

Tags: batch-file

Windows command "net view /domain" prints result as followed:

```
Domain

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
MSHOME                            
WORKGROUP            
Command Success
```

How can I remove the first and last 3 lines of the output text using a batch script?

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set ResultFile=Result_%random%.tmp

net view /domain > %ResultFile%
set fileLineCount=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%ResultFile%) do (
    set /A fileLineCount=fileLineCount+1
)

set WorkgroupFile=Workgroup_%random%.tmp
set /A LimitLine=fileLineCount-3
set Count=0
for /f "skip=3" %%i in (%ResultFile%) do (
    if !Count! LSS !LimitLine! (
        echo %%i >> %WorkgroupFile%
        set /A Count=Count+1
    ) 
)

del %ResultFile%
```

Comment: Note that `for /f` removes empty lines from the input which may not be what you want or need.

Answer (score 0):

i would use the unix tools head and/or tail
do you have cygwin or any other toolkit that allows you to use unix commands
windows has a vey poor command list

Comment: @echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set ResultFile=Result_%random%.tmp
REM 
net view /domain > %ResultFile%
set fileLineCount=0
for /f "delims=" %%i in (%ResultFile%) do (
 set /A fileLineCount=fileLineCount+1
)

set WorkgroupFile=Workgroup_%random%.tmp
set /A LimitLine=fileLineCount-3
set Count=0
for /f "skip=3" %%i in (%ResultFile%) do (
 if !Count! LSS !LimitLine! (
  echo %%i >> %WorkgroupFile%
  set /A Count=Count+1
 ) 
)

del %ResultFile%