# Counting isn't working in batch file

Tags: scripting, batch-file

I was trying to count the number of lines in a file using batch file (windows xp sp3).
Here is my code:

```
@echo off

set line=0
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (foo) do (
    set /A line+=1
    echo line count: %line%
    )

echo number of lines: %line%
```

Although it is counting the lines correctly, but the `echo` output isn't what I am expecting. I think this has some thing to do with delayed expansion of variable and so I tried `SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion` as well, but that's also not working.

here is the output that I am getting:

```
C:\fiddle\temp>a.bat
line count: 0
line count: 0
line count: 0
line count: 0
line count: 0
number of lines: 5
```

What's wrong in here?

FYI: I got into this while looking for an answer for [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593242/how-to-remove-the-first-and-last-3-lines-of-a-text-with-a-batch-script) question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add this line:

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
```

Change this line:

```
echo line count: %line%
```

to this:

```
echo line count: !line!
```

So, the entire script will look like this:

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set line=0
FOR /F "usebackq delims=" %%a in (foo) do (
    set /A line+=1
    echo line count: !line!
    )

echo number of lines: %line%
```

Answer (score 1):

the batch script I use to count number of lines is the following. call it from the command line with your input file as parameter.

```
@echo off & setLocal EnableDELAYedeXpansion

for /f "tokens=1 delims=[]" %%a in ('find /v /c "" ^< %1') do (
echo %~n1 %%a
)
```